# Prove $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{c+b}+\sqrt{a+c}\ge 2+\sqrt{a+b+c-\frac{5}{4}abc}$ for $ab+bc+ca=1.$

Tags: inequality

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that$$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{c+b}+\sqrt{a+c}\ge 2+\sqrt{a+b+c-\frac{5}{4}abc}.$$

---

I thought of [Jichen lemma](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h194103) but it seems not good enough.

Indeed, we'll rewrite as
$$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{c+b}+\sqrt{a+c}\ge 1+1+\sqrt{a+b+c-\frac{5}{4}abc}.$$
Now, I check
$$2(a+b+c)\ge 2+a+b+c-\frac{5}{4}abc\iff a+b+c+\frac{5}{4}abc\ge 2$$
is wrong when $a=b=c=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$

A big trouble is around $a=b=c=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.$ In this point, $LHS-RHS\approx 0.00244.$

I hope you can help me solve this problem. I'm appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Did you try LM ?

Comment: Can someone, which want to close this topic ,explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What did you mean? Why is the topic closed?

Comment: @TATA box Yes. Someone wants to close this topic

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of a proof.**

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{b + c} + \sqrt{c + a} &= \sqrt{b + c + c + a + 2\sqrt{(b + c)(a + c)}}\\
 &\ge \sqrt{a + b + 2c + 2(\sqrt{ab} + c)}.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{a + b} + \sqrt{a + b + 2c + 2(\sqrt{ab} + c)} \ge 2 + \sqrt{a + b + c - \frac54 abc}. \tag{1}$$

Let $p = a + b$ and $q = ab$.
We have $c = \frac{1 - ab}{a + b} = \frac{1 - q}{p}$. We have $1/3 \le q \le 1$ and $p^2 \ge 4q$ and $p \ge 2/\sqrt 3$.

(1) is written as
\begin{align*}
 f(q) &:= \sqrt{p} + \sqrt{p + 4\cdot \frac{1 - q}{p} + 2\sqrt{q}} - 2 - \sqrt{p + \frac{1 - q}{p} - \frac54 q\cdot \frac{1 - q}{p}}\\[6pt]
 &\ge 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to prove that $f(q)$ is concave on $(0, 1]$, given that $p \ge 2/\sqrt{3}$.

We split into two cases.

**Case 1.** $2/\sqrt{3} \le p < 2$

Using $a \ge b \ge c$ and $ab + bc + ca = 1$,
we have $ab + ab + a^2 \ge 1$ and $ab + b^2 + ab \ge 1$.
Thus, $(a^2 + 2ab - 1)(b^2 + 2ab - 1) \ge 0$
which is written as $q^2 + (2p^2 - 2)q - p^2 + 1 \ge 0$. Thus, we have $q \ge 1 - p^2 + p\sqrt{p^2 - 1}$.

It is easy to prove that $f(p^2/4) \ge 0$.
We can also prove that $f(1 - p^2 + p\sqrt{p^2 - 1}) \ge 0$ (*Note*: It is the difficult part. I think there is a better way.)

Thus, $f(q) \ge 0$ for all $1 - p^2 + p\sqrt{p^2 - 1} \le q \le p^2/4$.

**Case 2.** $p \ge 2$

It is easy to prove that $f(1/3) \ge 0$ and $f(1) \ge 0$.
Thus, $f(q) \ge 0$ for all $1/3 \le q \le 1$.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dragonboy You are welcome.